# Fast way to Update thousands unique row with PHP [not using loop]

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to to update huge numbers of unique rows from my db using php
Found out that the execution time could take more than 15minutes for 10k rows

Here's the code ...

sql table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `budget` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `carmaker` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carline` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phase` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purpose` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_plan` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `required_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subgroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curr` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_ori` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_reduce_ori` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_reduce_usd` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty_reduce` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty_final` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_final` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'uncommited',
  `source` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coa_production` char(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coa_general` char(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hfm_cr` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hfm_pl` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_record` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20331 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

update.php :

```
$dataQuery = query("SELECT * FROM budget WHERE section = '$section'");

        // print_r($dataQuery);die;

        foreach ($dataQuery as $key) {

            $qty = $key['qty'];
            $qty_pi = $key['qty_reduce'];
            $amount = $key['amount'];
            $amount_pi = $key['amount_reduce_usd'];
            $budget_id = $key['budget_id'];

            $qty_final = $qty - $qty_pi;
            $amount_final = $amount - $amount_pi;

            $cQuery = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE budget SET status = 'commited',qty_final = '$qty_final', amount_final = '$amount_final' WHERE section = '$section' AND budget_id = '$budget_id'");

            if ($cQuery == 1) {

              $_SESSION['msg'] = 'All records successfully commited';
              $_SESSION['heading'] = 'Success';
              $_SESSION['alert'] = 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show';

            } else {

                $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Failed to commit record.';
                $_SESSION ['alert']= 'alert alert-danger';
            }
```

Anyone got an idea how to speed it up ? 
i cannot use bulk update because those rows are unique and need to be checked and generate the amount
or can somebody told me how to use json to solve this case ?

Comment: Those columns storing subtraction values don't really make sense. The whole updated query seems unwanted except for `status` column if it wasn't `commited` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance the use of `$key['budget_id']` in your WHERE on the update does not appear to be needed. In addition, you may calculate the columns to be updated directly. And you shouldn't need to loop through the rows either, just do a single query and the actual row values will be used to update each row. That single query should execute in a fraction of a second.

```
$cQuery = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE budget 
SET `status`       = 'commited'       ,
    `qty_final`    = `qty` - `qty_reduce` , 
    `amount_final` = `amount` - `amount_reduce_usd`
WHERE section = '$section'");
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help, but just tried this, i did copu-paste from here and just add WHERE section = '$section' , turns out only status were updated, both qty_final and amount_final fields still blanks/null,  did i miss something ?

Comment: You don't need the WHERE. That query will operate on each row independently.

Comment: I need to use it because there are more than one section who will acces and commiting data, i need where to make sure only data/rows from their section (locked when login) will be executed/commited

Comment: I added your `WHERE` clause to my answer which should work as desired.

Comment: Do i need to add SUM before those calculation ?

Comment: No, you weren't doing that in your original question. I simply moved the calculations you were doing in PHP into the actual query itself using the column values in the math. Double check that I got the column names correct.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, this works exactly what I want, notes to myself : apparently yesterday the amount_reduce and qty_reduce were NULL, hence it cannot be calculated, after i remove them with 0 (zero), then it works perfectly !